# Different color representation for same circle

Tags: color, animation

```
h[x0_] := Module[{b = x0}, f[z_] := 2 z^2;
z[t_] := Cos[t] + I Sin[t];
w = ComplexExpand[f[z[t]]];
p1 = ParametricPlot[{Re[z[t]], Im[z[t]]}, {t, 0, b},PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle->{Red}];
p2 = ParametricPlot[{Re[w], Im[w]}, {t, 0, b}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Green}];
Show[p1, p2]]
Manipulate[h[p], {p, \[Pi]/10, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/10}]
```

We know that $f[z]:=2z^2$ represents a circle when $z$ moves from $0$ to $\pi$. Now, when $z$ moves from $\pi$ to $2\pi$, the function $f[z]$ takes one round of circle and complete the circle.

When the first round is completed by $f[z]$, the line continues to be shown in green color. I want $f[z]$ to change color when it starts on a new round.

Similarly, when it starts its third (or fourth and so on) round its color should change every time.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a color function that changes every $2\pi$:

```
z[t_] := Cos[t] + I Sin[t];

Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[
  {Re[z[t]], Im[z[t]]},
  {t, 0, tmax},
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, u}, ColorData[97, Quotient[u, 2 Pi]]],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.1]
  ],
 {tmax, 2 Pi, 10 Pi}
 ]
```

[image: Example]